# Drupal Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Hi I have the following drupal module

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_menu_alter().
*
* @param array $items
* Menu items keyed by path.
*/
function ajax_privacy_menu_alter(&$items) {

$items['node/%']['access callback'] = 'check_access';
$items['node/%']['access arguments'] = array(1);

}

function check_access($node_id)
{

if($node_id!=29)
return TRUE;
else
return FALSE;
}
```

If i type node/29 it returns access denied message as expected
but for other nodes ( eg: node/24 ) I get the following error

> Notice: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in
>   check_access() (line 19 of
>   /home/pagergbr/public_html/pagerail/sites/all/modules/ajax_privacy/ajax_privacy.module).

and all the nodes in my site show up along with node/24. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your access callback gets $node object as an argument, try this:

```
function check_access($node) {
  if ($node->nid != 29) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried it but now getting the error : Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$id

Comment: my apologies, there was a typo, try with $node->nid